# Fancybox: populate next/prev buttons with element titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there a method within Fancybox 2 to get the titles of the next and previous elements, and use those titles in the next and previous button templates so the title appears as the link?

Something like this:

```
tpl: {
  next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span>{next.title}</span></a>',
  prev: '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span>{prev.title}</span></a>'
}
```

I'm using Fancybox for a "step by step" tutorial. Instead of the next/prev arrows, I would like people to see the titles of the next/prev section - the title would be the link.

I've read through the js code and I don't think it's there, but I'm sure there is a way to get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but first you need to take in consideration

- how many elements exist in the gallery
- what is the previous `title` for the *first* element of the gallery (should be the *last*, if `loop` API option is set to `true` (default))
- what is the next `title` for the *last* element of the gallery (should be the *first*, if `loop` API option is set to `true`)

Then set the script that validates the conditions above within a fancybox callback (`afterShow`) and set the `title` attribute of the fancybox's *previous/next* navigation buttons to the corresponding value

so try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // loop: false, // gallery may not be cyclic 
        afterShow: function () {
            // initialize some variables
            var gallerySize = this.group.length,
                next, prev;
            if (this.index == gallerySize - 1) {
                // this is the last element of the gallery so next is the first
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(0).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");
            } else if (this.index == 0) {
                // this is the first image of the gallery so prev is the last
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(gallerySize - 1).attr("title");
            } else {
                // otherwise just add or substract to index
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");
            }
            // set title attributes to fancybox next/prev selectors
            $(".fancybox-next").attr("title", next);
            $(".fancybox-prev").attr("title", prev);
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PP5SN/)</kbd>

**Notice** that in my demo, the *second* element has not a `title` attribute, so fancybox will display either `next` or `previous` by default. Additionally, don't worry if `loop` is set to `false`, the navigation arrows won't show up for the first or last elements, so nothing further to do.

BTW, don't need to mess with the `TPL` option.

---

**EDIT** :

> One thing that's not ideal about my adaptation of this is that it adds the link texts afterShow. Because the link texts are positioned relatively, this causes a noticeable delay/adjustment in the display of the fancybox after it appears ...

Unfortunately, you can't set the text/title until the navigation arrows are shown. The same script within the `beforeShow` callback would be ignored and "next" and "previous" titles will be shown.

However, you can use the `$.extend()` method to modify the default value of the (template) `tpl` option before the navigation arrows are rendered (using the `beforeShow` callback) like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // loop: false, // gallery may not be cyclic 
        // preset titles before show
        beforeShow: function () {
            // initialize some variables
            var gallerySize = this.group.length,
                next, prev;
            if (this.index == gallerySize - 1) {
                // this is the last element of the gallery so next is the first
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(0).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");
            } else if (this.index == 0) {
                // this is the first image of the gallery so prev is the last
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(gallerySize - 1).attr("title");
            } else {
                // otherwise just add or substract to index
                next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
                prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");
            }
            // set title attributes to fancybox next/prev selectors
            //$(".fancybox-next").attr("title", next);
            //$(".fancybox-prev").attr("title", prev);
            //
            // use extend to modify the template
            $.extend(this, {
                tpl: {
                    next: '<a title="' + next + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
                    prev: '<a title="' + prev + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
                }
            }); // extend
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See updated <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PP5SN/1/)</kbd>

Comment: JFK, many thanks. I had been thinking I needed to hack the fancybox script itself, but it obviously outputs enough markup to be modified externally by a second script as you show here.

BTW I decided on using your script to change the "next"/"prev" text itself, rather than the title attr, so I changed your last two lines to `$(".fancybox-next").text(next); $(".fancybox-prev").text(prev);` - in case that may help someone else

Comment: One thing that's not ideal about my adaptation of this is that it adds the link texts afterShow. Because the link texts are positioned relatively, this causes a noticeable delay/adjustment in the display of the fancybox after it appears, as seen [in this test site here if you click on "options"](http://andrewnimmo.com/test/recent-work/posters/). 

I am reading through the code to try to understand if there's a way to add the text before the fancybox is displayed.